# Re-instating old user after upgrade

Tags: upgrade

This is a variation on questions about recovering user data.  During upgrade, I gave a new user name+password (by mistake: long story).  All my old data is there and I've backed it up, but I'd prefer to re-activate the old user name+password.  Users+Groups doesn't have it and 'su' won't switch to it because there's no password entry.  Is there a way of re-instating the old user account ?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why can't you use Users+Groups to re-create the user?

Comment: I didn't try that 'cos I feared I might erase all the old data: would like to keep old settings, etc.

Comment: Nothing gets deleted when creating a new user, just the files `/etc/passwd`,`/etc/group` and `/etc/shadow` will be touched. And also only in adding new lines to them. With the right parameters it auto creates home folders, but that can only happen if there is no folder like that already.

Comment: Thanks very much for this clarification.  I tried it and some of it worked.  However, when I try to login as the original, now recreated, user I don't get logged in, just bounced back to the login screen, with no message about a bad password.  And I'm pretty sure I got the password right.  Any ideas why this happens ?

Comment: Seems like the lightdm loop strikes again: explains why grand-daughter brought the machine for fix.  Now researching that issue.